# Web command to pass arguments to ddev exec?

Tags: ddev

Nowadays most CMS provide some kind of cli interface, like `./typo3cms` or in the case of craft `./craft`.

Instead of running `ddev exec ./craft do/something`, I'd like to add a web command `craft` that tunnels that `do/something`, so I can just write `ddev craft do/something`.

I understand this is nice to have :-)

But can I have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nice to have that you can, in fact, have right now. Check out the documentation on custom commands: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-commands/

Your integration would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Description: Run craft inside the web container
## Usage: craft [flags] [args]
## Example: "ddev craft some command"

craft $@
```